# WPF Control positioning difficulties

Tags: wpf, xaml

I try to do something supposed to be extrely easy but it is now 3 hours that i can't...

I try to have 2 buttons "OK" and "Cancel" close to another but it does not work , whatever i do on the cancel button it makes it invisible, here is the code:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Height="242">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.723"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.128"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.149*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.14"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.291*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.12*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.413*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.176*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="Please click the link next to get content." Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,2,4,2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <Hyperlink x:Name="hlLicense" Click="hlLicense_Click" TextDecorations="Underline" NavigateUri="Http://www.google.com" Foreground="#FFD24A4A">
            <Run Text="Http://www.google.com"/>
        </Hyperlink>
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBox Text="" TextWrapping="Wrap"  AcceptsReturn="True" x:Name="tbLicense" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
    <TextBlock Foreground="Red"  Name="messageLabel" Grid.Column="0" Text="" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
    <Button Content="OK"  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Width="87.083" Height="25.277" x:Name="btnActive"  Click="btnActive_Click"     />
    <Button Width="87.083" Content="Cancel" IsCancel="True" Grid.Column="3" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="3"  />

</Grid>
```

Thanks
John

Comment: you appear to be overlapping your cancel button (col 3, row 3) with your last TextBlock (col-span 3, row 3)

Comment: ok, but i found no way to fix this ! Nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with your ColumnDefinition widths. When you take those out, it's drawn just fine. Your widths are too small, and the OK button's column's width is set to a * so it autosizes to fill the extra space.

this will show your cancel button fine because it's column will auto-adjust:

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.723"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.128"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.149*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.14*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

I don't know if that's exactly what you want, but you can work with it from there to do exactly what you need.